# Dateparser strict parsing doesn't seem to work for "45 Days"

Tags: python, dateparser

According to dateparser documentation:

```
parse('December 2015', settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})
```

returns `None`.

I would expect that `parse('45 Days', settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})`, would also return `None`. However it returns a datetime object corresponding to `2022-04-03 16:04:35.533484`. Maybe it's counting 45 days back from today, when we run the command.

I would like the parse to return None instead, in this case...
I've even tried

```
parse("45 Days",languages=['en'],
                        settings={'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY',
                        'REQUIRE_PARTS': ['month','day','year']})
```

but I get the same object.

Comment: https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/issues/1057 . Perhaps that's even an issue you filed?

Comment: @9769953 =D =D I had completely forgotten about that...